# Software to read fingerprint and generate a unique number

Tags: linux, open-source, hardware

Is there any **open-source** software available to read fingerprint from fingerprint scanner and give a unique number ?

I need this for another software I am building where I need to store user's fingerprint in a database.

I use Linux. So I am searching for any of these kind which runs on Linux.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There has been considerable discussion of doing this with [Open CV](http://opencv.org/) on the OpenCV forum, there is an example in a book called [Open CV 3 Blueprints](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/fingerprint-detection-using-opencv-3) and the associated C++ source code can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenCVBlueprints/OpenCVBlueprints/tree/master/chapter_6/source_code/fingerprint/fingerprint_process/).

You can also find C# & Java implementations [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourceafis/).